# Problem formatting DataGridView on load

Tags: datagridview

I'm trying to format a DataGridView, with style color, etc. 
The DGV loads (via buildGrid method) at the startup of the form, as you can see in the constructor's code:

```
    public Report1(DataSet dsReport1, string sDateRep)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sDate = sDateRep;
        dsReportGrid = dsReport1;
        orgDataset();
        buildGrid();
    }
```

Here's the code for the DGV:

```
    private void buildGrid()
    {
     try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsReportGrid.Tables[0];
            Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
            dataGridView1.Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It loads the DGV fine,  problem is that it won't color the cells like I wish it would, it's just leaves it black.

Funny thing, when I call buildGrid through any other method, outside of the constructor, it does color it! for example:

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        buildGrid();
    }
```

Why is it happening? How can I make it color the cells right from the beginning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the databinding has not yet completed inside your constructur so any changes to the grid are removed (I'm not actually 100% sure **why** they are removed, since the rows and cells are there, but this is how it works).

The correct place to put this sort of formatting is within the `DataBindingComplete` event handler - that event is raised after databinding has finished but before the grid is drawn.

```
public Report1(DataSet dsReport1, string sDateRep)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sDate = sDateRep;
    dsReportGrid = dsReport1;
    orgDataset();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dsReportGrid.Tables[0];
    Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;

    dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
}

void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: This did solve a problem in a legacy application for me, but it turns out this event can fire A LOT (and none of the solutions/workarounds I could find helped). I ended up opting for the simpler solution of using the Form.Shown event, which only fires once.